# Update image in database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I need to add a photo update function.

HTML form:

```
<form action="scripts/setImage.php" method="post"> 
  <h3>Set my image:</h3>
  Choose photo:<br><br>
  <input type="file" name="file"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">      
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$file = $_POST['file'];
if (isset($_POST['file'])) {
    $db->UPDATE("UPDATE users SET image = LOAD_FILE('$file') WHERE id = $idLogged");
}
```

And this doesn't work ;/ I think I can't use `$_POST` with files. I tried also `$_FILES` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: In the db you only store the name of the imageand or link to the image. If you want to store the image in the db, the field must ba a BLOB type. Normally the image is stored as a file on your server.

Comment: read this first https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: Add to form enctype='multipart/form-data.

Comment: And check documentation - https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: Grumpy, it's blow type. And I have images in databases but can't update it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<form action="scripts/setImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
    <h3>Set my image:</h3>
    Choose photo:<br><br>
    <input type="file" name="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sumbit">      
</form>

<?php
    $file =addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']));
    if (isset($file)) {
        $db->UPDATE("UPDATE users SET image = '$file' WHERE id = $idLogged");
    }
?>
```

Comment: I did it and NULL is set to database

Comment: Yes, it works. Why did you need to add "addlashes" and "file_get_contents"?

Comment: `file_get_contents()` for get image contents and `addlashes` for ignore special characters for the time of updating data in table.